# Customizing Visual Studio's Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio, ide, customization

A recent project had me working with C# again, and I noticed something I hadn't before -- C#'s Intellisense shows possible exceptions that can be thrown when calling a method

[image]

Since I work mostly with VB.NET applications, it'd be really nice to have this feature in those applications as well, but it's unfortunately absent from VB's Intellisense

[image]

Is there any quick and easy way I can customize Visual Studio's Intellisense to show exceptions (as well as other members from the XML comments)?  Or am I looking at a full modification using the SDK?

Update: 29-Sep-2008 1:49 PM -- I figure this will be more complicated than simply changing a configuration setting.  Since the comments are XML-based, I was hoping for an XSLT file somewhere buried in the Visual Studio directory, but nothing has turned up so far.  Looks like I'm going to have to dig into the Visual Studio SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Try going to Tool -> Options...
Then Text Editor ->  Basic
and make sure both options "Auto list members" and "hide advanced members" are unchecked.
Also check "Parameter information".

I cannot validate this information because my current Visual Studio installation is C# standalone.

Regards,
Luís

Comment: AH, so that is what that means! I always wondered  :)  Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it. "Hide advanced members" controls whether "advanced", (e.g. non-overriden, inherited members) are shown.